# Cannot Delete Existing File in Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, webserver

I have uploaded my website to the web server. I have an option to upload download and delete files. I am in the middle of testing and all is going smoothly. I tried uploading a file, I deleted it and it completely works. But when I am trying to delete an existing file, it throws an error:

> *An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

I knew that it has something to do with permissions. When I compared the permissions present in the file that I have uploaded through the site, it shows **.NET v4.5** while in the existing file, there is no such user. I tried adding it but there is no .NET v 4.5.

I tried adding NETWORK SERVICE and gave it full permission but still no luck. I hope you could help me guys on this one.

UPDATE:

Here is the exception details:

> *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\"MyFilePath"' is denied. 
>   ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>   To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.*

Comment: Could you please add the exception details ?

Comment: @Boney I have added the exception details in my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: The identity under which the application pool runs should have delete rights to the file it is trying to delete.
Can you please let me know the identity of the AppPool under which the site runs ? 
Try changing the AppPool to 'ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated' and grant group 'IIS_IUSRS' access to that folder.

Comment: It has solved my problem! Many thanks @Boney :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)
Shall i add it as answer, so that you can accept it ?

Comment: yes you can. :) I'l accept it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Added as answer. Thank you as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity under which the application pool runs should have delete rights to the file it is trying to delete.
Try changing the AppPool to 'ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated' and grant group 'IIS_IUSRS' access to that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! :)